# Connect to Azure Storage blob Behind Proxy: The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://ipaddress:port/' failed with status code '407'

Tags: proxy, webproxy

Follow code available on Microsoft documentation portal but what if I want add the proxy to it? I'm using **.NET Core 6+**

```
string blobstorageconnection = pConfig.AzuerBlobStorageConnectionString;
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobstorageconnection);
CloudBlobClient? blobClient = null;
CloudBlockBlob? blockBlob = null;
blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(pConfig.AzureStorageContainerName);
blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(pFileName);
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(pFilePath + @"\" + pFileName);
```

I tried above code and it is working fine without proxy setting in network but as we enable the proxy setting system raise the error : **"The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://ipaddress:port/' failed with status code '407'."**

Comment: Issue raised in GitHub
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/31390
After searching a lot, I got nothing in my hand.

Comment: MS team also roaming around by saying not a Azure issue.
Let's see who will give the answer on it.

Comment: Very silly thing happen with me in GitHub Azure Organisation community. They simply closed my issue (github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/31390) by saying deprecated version. But they should ask me before closing the ticket and also they should simply check the code what I submitted in the issue ticket for review. Without reviewing they simply closed that. It is showing the frustration of the team member. 

Comment: Still playing around instead of accepting the documentation issue. It is always not possible to get the correct meaning from documentation. Documentation should be clear but here MS documentation is confusing.